# Load accounts to truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, wallets, accounts

I'm using truffle v5.0.14 to handle my contracts. 
All was well while developing with ganache, but when I wanted to deploy to the real network (a private one) I have problems with the account.

The node that I have to connect to prevents from unlocking accounts for rpc calls, so what is the correct way to load my account to truffle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All accounts in Ganache are unlocked by default, but when you want to connect to other network and deploy contracts there (using truffle) then you should use this library

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider,

Answer (score 0):

This is a rite of passage.

A favorite one-liner, *in the Geth console*:

`web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.personal.listAccounts[0],"<password>", 15000);`

Meaning, unlock my first account, with this password, for 15,000 seconds (i.e. don't bother me for a while).

When you are finished, manually lock it or just restart the node.

PSA: Don't expose the `personal` API over RPC. That would help you get it to work from truffle and/or scripts but it might start responding to other people, and that would be bad.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Rob! I can't call the unlock method because web3 says that 'unlock is forbidden for HTTP'. I could run the geth node with the allow-insecure-unlock flag, but I guess there must be a better way. But I'm no expert, that's why I asked